# FLTK 1.3 Linking errors

Tags: c++, cmake, fltk

I update my FLTK from 1.1 to 1.3, then I can't compile my code which is worked well before update.

```
...
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/PROSTVIEW.dir/include/nifti/vtkznzlib.cxx.o
    Linking CXX executable PROSTVIEW
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `fontopen(char const*, int, bool, int)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `FcPatternCreate'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x362): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddString'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x3e3): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddString'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x3f7): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddInteger'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x40b): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddInteger'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddDouble'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddString'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x4df): undefined reference to `FcMatrixRotate'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x4f7): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddMatrix'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddBool'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to `FcPatternAddBool'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x549): undefined reference to `XftFontMatch'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x5a0): undefined reference to `XftFontOpen'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x5b0): undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x5f3): undefined reference to `XftFontOpenPattern'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x603): undefined reference to `FcPatternDestroy'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x659): undefined reference to `XftFontOpenXlfd'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `utf8extents(Fl_Font_Descriptor*, char const*, int, _XGlyphInfo*)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x84b): undefined reference to `XftTextExtents32'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `fl_xft_width(Fl_Font_Descriptor*, unsigned int*, int)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x98a): undefined reference to `XftTextExtents32'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `fl_destroy_xft_draw(unsigned long)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x102e): undefined reference to `XftDrawChange'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `Fl_Xlib_Graphics_Driver::draw(char const*, int, int, int)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x10c6): undefined reference to `XftDrawCreate'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x10f6): undefined reference to `XftDrawChange'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1140): undefined reference to `XftDrawSetClip'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1202): undefined reference to `XftDrawString32'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `fl_drawUCS4(Fl_Graphics_Driver*, unsigned int const*, int, int, int)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1313): undefined reference to `XftDrawCreate'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1343): undefined reference to `XftDrawChange'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x138d): undefined reference to `XftDrawSetClip'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1433): undefined reference to `XftDrawString32'
    /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_font.cxx.o): In function `Fl_Xlib_Graphics_Driver::rtl_draw(char const*, int, int, int)':
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x1480): undefined reference to `FcUtf8Len'
    fl_font.cxx:(.text+0x14ff): undefined reference to `FcUtf8ToUcs4'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [PROSTVIEW] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROSTVIEW.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(PROSTVIEW)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
SET(CMAKE_CXX__FLAGS -O3 -pipe -ffast-math -Wno-deprecated)

# Chargement Package
# FLTK
 FIND_PACKAGE ( FLTK )
 IF ( FLTK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR} )
 ENDIF ( FLTK_FOUND )

# ITK
FIND_PACKAGE ( ITK )
IF ( ITK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE( ${USE_ITK_FILE} )
ENDIF( ITK_FOUND ) 

# VTK
FIND_PACKAGE ( VTK )
IF ( VTK_FOUND )
    INCLUDE( ${USE_VTK_FILE} )
ENDIF( VTK_FOUND )
SET(VTK_LIBRARIES vtkCommon vtkRendering vtkWidgets vtkGraphics vtkGenericFiltering vtkzlib)

# vtkFlRenderWindowInteractor
SET(VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR "include/vtkfl")
SET(VTKFL_CPP 
${VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR}/vtkFlRenderWindowInteractor.cxx)

# Auxiliary_Tools
SET(AT_DIR "include/Auxiliary_Tools")
SET(AT_INCLUDE_DIR ${AT_DIR}/include)
SET(AT_LIBRARY_DIR ${AT_DIR}/lib)

#Nifty
SET(NII_DIR "include/nifti")
SET(NII_SRC 
${NII_DIR}/vtkNIfTIReader.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkNIfTIWriter.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkAnalyzeReader.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkAnalyzeWriter.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtknifti1_io.cxx
${NII_DIR}/vtkznzlib.cxx)

#Other include
SET(PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR "include")
SET(PROSTVIEW_SRC
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/ContourTmt.cpp
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/conversion.cpp 
${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR}/TmtMatrix.cpp) 

# VOLUME Widget
SET(VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR "include/GUI")
SET(VOLUME_WIDGET 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Loader.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Widget.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_Mouse_Widget.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/VOLUME_3DView.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/CONTOUR_Loader.cpp 
${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR}/ProstView.cpp)

# MODULES
SET(MODULE_DIR "Module")

# SEGMENTATION
SET(SEGMENTATION_DIR "Module/Segmentation")
SET(SEGMENTATION 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC2D.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3D.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DHu.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DPlus.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/DDC3DBal.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/IMAGE_ENERGY.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/REGULARIZATION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/OPTIMAL_SURFACE_DETECTION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/OPTIMAL_MULTIPLE_SURFACES_DETECTION.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RESAMPLE_From_Prostate.cpp
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RECTAL_WALL_US.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/BLADDER_MRI.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/RECTUM_MRI.cpp 
${SEGMENTATION_DIR}/REGION_GROWING.tpp )

#MESH
SET(MESH_DIR "Module/Mesh")
SET(MESH
${MESH_DIR}/GENERIC_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/ELLIPSOID_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/PROSTATE_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/TUBULAR_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/OPEN_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/QUADRIC_MESH.cpp
${MESH_DIR}/ELLIPTICAL_CYLINDER_MESH.cpp 
${MESH_DIR}/CONTOURS_MAN_MESH.cpp)

#STUDY
SET(STUDY_DIR "Module/Statistics")
SET(STUDY
${STUDY_DIR}/PROFILE.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/Histogram.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/HISTOGRAM_FROM_MESH.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/TRAINING_SET_ALIGNMENT.cpp
${STUDY_DIR}/APPEARANCE_MODEL.cpp)

# MOMENTS
SET(MOMENTS_DIR "Module/Moments")
SET(MOMENTS 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/KRAWTCHOUK_Moments.tpp 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/TCHEBICHEF_Moments.tpp 
${MOMENTS_DIR}/GEOMETRIC_Moments.tpp)

#VALIDATION
SET(VALIDATION_DIR "Module/Evaluation")
SET(VALIDATION 
${VALIDATION_DIR}/Metrics.cpp)

# Include et Link Directories
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTKFL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${NII_DIR} ${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR} ${MODULE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${FLTK_LIBRARY_DIR} ${VTK_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${AT_LIBRARY_DIR} ${PROSTVIEW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VOLUME_WIDGET_DIR} ${MODULE_DIR})

# Sources
SET(SRC main.cpp) 

# Executables and "stand-alone " librairies
ADD_EXECUTABLE(PROSTVIEW ${SRC} ${PROSTVIEW_SRC} ${VTKFL_CPP} ${VOLUME_WIDGET} ${SEGMENTATION} ${MESH} ${STUDY} ${MOMENTS} ${VALIDATION} ${NII_SRC})

# Linkage
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PROSTVIEW  ${FLTK_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

I tried to add some libs in my CMakeLists.txt, but it's not work. Who can tell me what’s the problem?

Comment: Please make use of Ctrl-K for formatting, it appears better! :)

Comment: Error looks like, linker problems. Did you happen to remove some libraries for linking?

Comment: I posted my cmakelist file which works before. But when I remove the fltk1.1 and install fltk1.3, I'm not sure if some libraries are missing.

Comment: Maybe the dependencies for 1.3 has changed from 1.1 for the libraries. From the error it looks like fontconfig & Xft libraries are the ones which are missing. Maybe you can try to add them in Cmakelist

Comment: These symbols have something to do with fontconfig. Did you tried `make clean`?

Comment: Thank you all. I link libfontconfig.so and libXft.so to my project and it works. TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(PROSTVIEW libfontconfig.so libXft.so).

Comment: Yep, that was obviously the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From FLTK 1.3's README.CMake.txt:

> ## USING CMAKE WITH FLTK
>
> This howto assumes that you have FLTK libraries which were built using
>   CMake, installed.  Building them with CMake generates some CMake
>   helper files which are installed in standard locations, making FLTK
>   easy to find and use.
>
> Here is a basic CMakeLists.txt file using FLTK.
>
> ---
>
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
>
> project(hello)
>
> find_package(FLTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE) include(${FLTK_USE_FILE})
>
> add_executable(hello WIN32 hello.cxx)
>
> target_link_libraries(hello fltk)
>
> ---
>
> The find_package command tells CMake to find the package FLTK,
>   REQUIRED means that it is an error if it's not found.  NO_MODULE tells
>   it to search only for the FLTKConfig file, not using the
>   FindFLTK.cmake supplied with CMake, which doesn't work with this
>   version of FLTK.
>
> Once the package is found we include the ${FLTK_USE_FILE} which adds
>   the FLTK include directories and library link information to its
>   knowledge base.  After that your programs will be able to find FLTK
>   headers and when you link the fltk library, it automatically links the
>   libraries fltk depends on.

It seems that from FLTK 1.1 to 1.3 they changed the method needed to find the library, maybe for comparability/testing reasons?

I got hung up on the same issue, hope someone finds this useful. :)